# Fire trigger on updates (excluding certain fields change)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've defined my trigger like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trtablename]
    ON [dbo].[tablename]
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS update tablename set row_version = row_version + 1 
       where id in (select id from inserted)
```

There's a field called `Row_Status`. It should be modified without incrementing `row_version` field. How do I make such a condition in the trigger?

Comment: Modifying manually and using a trigger is kind of the opposite of one another.

Comment: What I meant is that modification of the field shouldn't lead to `row_version` change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a condition based on the [UPDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) function that can be called in triggers.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trtablename] ON [dbo].[tablename]
AFTER UPDATE
AS

If not update(Row_Status)
begin

  update tablename set row_version = row_version + 1 
  where id in (select id from inserted)

end
```

Depending on your table/columns and the likely `UPDATE` operations that might occur you may have to increase the complexity of the the check, but hopefully this points you in the correct direction.

Comment: Perhaps in combination with `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` function to check whatever `Row_status` was only updated column or some other was updaed also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

Comment: @NenadZivkovic, thanks, that's a great suggestion. Depending on the table complexity that could make things much easier.

Comment: @brick Whenever an update query is not hand-crafted there is a possibility that it updates all non-calculated columns in a record (ie. ORMs, MS Access, updates generated by Ado.Net target all columns). In this situation `Row_status` will be considered as updated even if it weren't touched by the application. If this is your situation you might join `inserted` and `deleted` on `id` and `row_status` thus allowing row_version change only if statuses in both tables do not differ.

Answer (score 2):

The only down side to using the `UPDATE` function is that it will be true if the field is even mentioned in the update statement.  Even if it is being set to itself.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trtablename]
ON [dbo].[tablename]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF NOT UPDATE (Row_Status) 
    update tablename set row_version = row_version + 1 
       where id in (select id from inserted)
```