# How to Exclude DB Column in a Trigger Function (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers, ddl

I have created a very simple trigger in a certain table (*e.g. TABLE_TRIGGER*) that will call a procedure (*handles all the logic*). This table has a column (*e.g. AUDITID*) which I would like to **exclude** in the trigger function, I mean, if **update** is only done in AUDITID column, the procedure should not be executed.

Below is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE_TRIGGER_FUNCTION
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON TABLE_TRIGGER
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- procedure();
END;
```

Is there other way to do it, other than the one suggested here: [Oracle: excluding updates of one column for firing a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421645/oracle-excluding-updates-of-one-column-for-firing-a-trigger)

The answer provided here is the one I would like to have [Fire trigger on updates (excluding certain fields change)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487758/fire-trigger-on-updates-excluding-certain-fields-change) but I am not sure if this is something that can also be done using Oracle PL/SQL syntax.

By the way, I have tried using the following **WHEN** statement by excluding the AUDITID column but the trigger did not work at all and the procedure was not executed.

```
WHEN (NEW.FILEID != OLD.FILEID OR
        NEW.DESCRIPTION != OLD.DESCRIPTION OR
        NEW.IMAGEID != OLD.IMAGEID OR
        NEW.STATETYPEID != OLD.STATETYPEID OR
        NEW.ACCESSLEVELID != OLD.ACCESSLEVELID OR
        NEW.FILETYPEID != OLD.FILETYPEID)
```

Comment: Are you handling three-valued logic correctly?  On an `insert`, `old.fileID` will always be NULL.  NULL is never unequal to any other value including NULL.  You may want `new.fileID != old.fileID or (new.fileID is null and old.fileID is not null) or (new.fileID is not null and old.fileID is null)`.  If there are values that you can ensure will never appear in the data, you could use a NVL rather than listing out all three possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to exclude a column from an update trigger, but you could define a list of columns it **would** fire on, and list all the columns except the `auditid`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE_TRIGGER_FUNCTION
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   OF FILEID, -- Field list starts here...
      DESCRIPTION,
      IMAGEID,
      STATETYPEID,
      ACCESSLEVELID,
      ACCESSLEVELID,
      FILETYPEID -- ... and ends here
   ON TABLE_TRIGGER
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- procedure();
END;
```

Comment: As I have a very small table for this trigger, I have to accept this answer because having this works for my current requirement.

Answer (score 0):

During insets ,all the references to OLD for insert event will result in NULL hence your procedure is not gonna run.

Consider and refer the below code blocks:
I think this is something you are looking for.

```
create table hr.test(id1 int,id2 int);

create or replace procedure hr.test_proc
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('trigger');
end;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trg
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON hr.test
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if updating and :old.id1 !=:new.id1 then
      null;--do nothing just as you want
    else 
      hr.test_proc;--call your proc
    end if;           
END;
```

Comment: May I know why it's a -2 on my answer?